# AE Script to change font style

Tags: javascript, extendscript, after-effects

Could someone help me by advising why the last line in below code is not working? The objective is to set the font style to bold of a text layer.

```
var myComp = app.project.activeItem;
var myTextLayer = myComp.layer(1);
var mySourceText = myTextLayer.property("ADBE Text Properties").property("ADBE Text Document");
var myTextDoc = mySourceText.value;
myTextDoc.ScriptUIFont.style.setValue(["Bold"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any way to change the style directly without changing the font.

You need to change the `font` attribute in `myTextDoc` to the desire font.

```
myTextDoc.font = 'Arial-BoldMT';
mySourceText.setValue(myTextDoc);
```

If the only change you want is to make it bold, you can use `fauxBold` attribute (It's a bit different, but maybe it'll make you satisfy).

```
myTextDoc.fauxBold = true;
mySourceText.setValue(myTextDoc);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `textDocument.font` property to the style name (without spaces), put a dash and write a font style with a captial letter. For example `"NunitoSans-Bold"` or `"Montserrat-SemiBold"`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will give it a try.